# Cracks in new construction home post tension concrete garage

Tags: concrete, garage, crack

We just had our walkthrough and we were informed by our builder of this long crack in our garage that was repaired with epoxy. Based on my research, it seems like it isn't a major issue. I am still a little nervous about it though.

We are near our closing date, so not sure if there is much we can do. Does anyone have any past experience with this or should we have a structural engineer look at it (if there's even enough time)? Any advice would be appreciated!

---

[image: here is an image of the crack]

Here is an image of the crack. It has been repaired with epoxy by the builder

Comment: Need more details. Big crack? Little crack? Is this floor or ceiling? Did they just dump a bit of epoxy or do they have an engineer’s stamp on the repair? Do you have a lawyer on speed dial?

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please consider [registering](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and most importantly [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers). Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Which way do the tendons run, relative to that repair? Parallel or perpendicular?